# Looping through files in different directories

Tags: bash

I want to write a script to loop through files in two different directories, and echo the files of different filename patterns
I made one like this but it is inappropriate

```
#Files in one dir ABC-123-1.txt
#Files in subdir ABC-123.doc
for f in *.doc
  do
  f1=`echo $f|sed 's/.doc//g`'
  for f2 in ../*.txt
     do
     f3=`echo $f2|sed 's/..\///g'|sed 's/-1.txt//g'`
     if [ "$f1" != "$f3" ]
        then
        echo $f3
     fi
    done
  done
```

Comment: You shouldn't use sed for simple string manipulation of variables. You also need to quote things properly to avoid mangling the output. You've messed up the quoting completely in at least one place, an excellent reason you should [never use backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). It isn't very clear what you want or why. For comparing files you probably want `[[`. `[` can't do pattern matching, only string comparison.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you intend to do with your script, you want to iterate over the files ending in ".doc" in dir1 and then print the files in dir2 with the same file name and ending "-1.txt".

This can be achieved in bash with this one liner:

```
for i in `ls <dir1>/*.doc | sed 's/\.doc$//'`; do ls <dir2>/"$i"-1.txt; done  2> /dev/null
```

(replace dir1 and dir2 with your directories)

The "2>/dev/null" will ignore files that do not match in the second directory and will only print the ones that do match.

Hope that helps.